# How to determine which theme is currently enabled

Tags: themes

I am not sure about the command, but I would like to know how to determine which theme is currently enabled on Ubuntu 14.04.

I am hoping for a command line solution.

Comment: yes that is what i mean

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `gsettings` to show currently enabled gtk theme:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
```

and set eg. Radiance

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Radiance
```

Answer (score 6):

If only want to know which themes are available on your system you can look into these two directory:

- `/usr/share/themes`
- `~/.themes`

The above directories contains the themes folder.

If you also want to know which is the current active theme you can follow these two way:

- Open `System Settings` and then choose `Appereance`. Now in the `Look` tab watch at the window bottom right: you can see which theme is currently set (e.g `Ambiance`);
- Install `unity-tweak-tool` to manage unity appearance:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
  ```

  Now open it and select `Themes` section. It will be shown the list of themes installed on your system and you can choose which is the best for you or you can install other from internet.

*Note*: if you have installed a new theme, then you can't see with the first method. Unfortunately you need a third-party software to manage themes different from default.

**EDIT**:
I you want to know which is the current active theme from terminal you can use this command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
```

I hope this could help you.

Comment: thanks for trying but currently  - `System Settings` -->`Appereance`-->  `Look` bottom right panel is greyed out (blank), as there is third party installed. Unity Tweak tool only shows available themes, not what is currently installed.

Comment: What is the content of the two directory that I post above (could you post the output of `ls /usr/share/themes`)? Which is theme are you currently using?

Answer (score 0):

### 18.04 and later

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later install the Tweaks application with `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`, open Tweaks from the Dash, and click the *Appearance* category in the left pane. The currently enabled theme is shown under the **Themes** heading and is marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshots.

[image: Tweaks → Appearance → Themes]
<sup>**Ubuntu 22.04**</sup>

[image: Tweaks → Appearance → Themes]
<sup>**Ubuntu 18.04**</sup>

Comment: OP wants a command-line method.

Comment: in v 22.04 everything is gone.

Answer (score 0):

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme` is correct, but I find it easier to use the `dconf` GUI for that.  You can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then open it by running `dconf` from the Start menu, e.g. click the Super key and type it, and navigate to the correct setting, which for my machine currently shows:

[image]